# Sitecore EXM 3.3 Subscription Form decoding message issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-exm

I use Exm Subscription Form on my site. When I click "Submit" nothing happen and I see in log this exception:

```
11:47:00 ERROR unhandled exception thrown while processing task '0x479FA17B72734C448A640E959089B01F' from task pool 'sent_message_task_pool'. The task has not reached the maximum number of Attempts to process a failing task and is postponed.
Exception: System.FormatException
Message: The input is not a valid base-64 string, since they in the voids containing a non-base 64 character, more than two spaces or a character that is not valid.
Source: mscorlib
at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode (char * startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte * startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr (char * inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
at System.Convert.FromBase64String (String s)
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Crypto.AuthenticatedAesStringCipher.TryDecrypt (String encryptedmessage)
at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Tasks.MessageEventBaseTaskProcessor.OnProcess (Short Running Task task, CancellationToken CancellationToken)
at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Tasks.Processing.ShortRunning.TaskProcessor.Process(ShortRunningTask task, CancellationToken CancellationToken)
at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Tasks.Processing.ShortRunning.DatabaseTaskAgent.ProcessTask(DatabaseTaskDtoCollectionItem taskDto, CancellationToken CancellationToken)
11:47:01 WARN One or more tasks processed by task agent 'sent_message_task_pool' failed. The agent wants to revert to the slowest processing speed possible.
```

This started happening when I upgraded EXM version from 3.2 to 3.3. In 3.2 version all worked fine

I found a line on which is happend this exception:

```
string str3 = this._cipher.TryDecrypt(eventData.ContactId);
```

It's look like that ContactId(equal "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") is missing

Comment: Please try to remove all folders under the <pathToRoot>\Data\viewstate folder and try to reproduce this issue again

Comment: issue still reproduced

Comment: I found a line on which is happend this exception:

string str3 = this._cipher.TryDecrypt(eventData.ContactId);

It's look like that ContactId(equal "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") is missing. Where it should be filled?

Comment: Have you added the required connectionstrings i.e. EXM.CryptographicKey and EXM.AuthenticationKey? c.f. the installation guide on https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/Email_Experience_Manager_33/Email_Experience_Manager_33_Initial_Release.aspx

Comment: yes, I've added this values

Comment: I just upgraded and I'm having the same exception. I have received the test email I sent through 'Send quick test' though

Comment: How to generate these keys..EXM.CryptographicKey and EXM.AuthenticationKey

Comment: same issue here did you find the problem?

Comment: I have used the keys provided in the installation doc of 3.3. Also tried with new keys it still gives same error

Answer (score 0):

What is your Sitecore version? Is it 8.1 Update 3? if not, Did you also update your Sitecore Version? As EXM 3.3 requires Sitecore 8.1 update 3

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/Email_Experience_Manager_33/Email_Experience_Manager_33_Initial_Release.aspx

[image]

Comment: Sitecore version 8.1 Update 3 - Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)